# Can an application developer launch an activity of mine (that has been exported) from a notification?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications

I have an activity that is has `exported=true` in the manifest. I am currently doing some logic to see if the activity was started from an activity of ***my*** application, or from ***another*** application.

What worries me is that if I set up a notification with an intent from within my application, the activity started by the notification click falls into my logic of "being started from the outside." I am having a problem because even though this is started from the "outside", it gets put into my current task stack. I can fix this with some intent flags, (like clear_top I assume), but I don't want another application to create a notification to start an activity of mine, because it'll be tacked onto my current task stack.

The Notification builder docs say:

> Although actions are optional, you should add at least one action to
>   your notification. An action takes users directly from the
>   notification to an Activity in your application, where they can look
>   at the event that caused the notification or do further work.

The main point being `An action takes users directly from the
notification to an Activity in **your** application`.

Bonus question: Can another application start an activity of mine and put that activity in my applications current task stack?

**EDIT:** I know the easiest way to test something is to just try it, so I created my own sample app to try to test this out. It doesn't seem to work though. It doesn't start the activity (which is good), but it doesn't crash, and it doesn't seem to do anything at all, so I think it might be incorrect?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Intent intent;
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent;
    Intent resultIntent;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout);
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.rootView);

        Button button1 = new Button(this);


        button1.setText("Send notification");
        intent = new Intent();
        resultIntent = new Intent();
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.myapp.tester",
                "com.myapp.tester.MyMainActivity"));
        final PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(
                this,
                0,
                resultIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );


        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                        new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                        .setContentTitle("My notification")
                        .setContentText("Hello World!");


                // Because clicking the notification opens a new ("special") activity, there's
                // no need to create an artificial back stack.


                mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);


                int mNotificationId = 001;
                // Gets an instance of the NotificationManager service
                NotificationManager mNotifyMgr = 
                        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                // Builds the notification and issues it.
                mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());

            }
        });
        layout.addView(button1);



    }

}
```

Comment: If I recall, a PendingIntent has some capability to forward a custom permission, which you might explore.  Alternately you could put a do-it-yourself one-time authorization token in an in intent extra, and check it upon receipt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notification's just take a PendingIntent.  Since a PendingIntent can be built around any intent, I think you should be able to make one that calls another application.  Worse case you create one that calls your application, which immediately calls the other.  But I don't think that's necessary, I think you can just put in the intent you want directly.

Comment: Exactly! A notification takes a PendingIntent, which could be an intent to my application. I would appreciate you taking a look at my sample. I'm not sure why my test case DOESN'T start my activity.

Comment: You have 2 different intent objects.  I think you may have gotten them mixed up.  You're adding resultIntent to the pending intent, but aren't setting anything on the resultIntent (you set it on intent).

Comment: Oh man. Alright, I guess I've been looking at this for too long. Thanks! I was hoping this wouldn't be the case though. As my test code works, it messes up my task stack. Any ideas on how to not have an outside application create a new activity in my current task stack?

Comment: Its one of the intent activity flags.  I think FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK?

Comment: Yes, but if another dev comes along, he won't know to do this. Which is essentially my problem. Any help with the bonus question? " Can another application start an activity of mine and put that activity in my applications current task stack?"

Comment: FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP is probably the closest fit.  But that's a subset at best of what you want.  At some point you have to assume the next dev who comes along knows how to use Android, or at least knows how to google to figure out how to get the experiences he wants.  NEW_TASK isn't exactly obscure functionality, its intermediate level knowledge.

Comment: Understandable. Thanks.